# What to do with gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, intel-atom

I have downloaded gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip from the following site. they said it contains libraries from Google map and Google Play services, so that I can develop apps using those.

http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip

The problem is I dont know how to use it.
Can anybody tell how to use it.
The user manual is not there in their web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have clockwork mod. If you don't, get that first.
After entering into clockwork mod (boot to bootloader->recovery) go mounts and storage. Mount your phone and copy your gapps file into your sdcard. The whole zip.
Next, go back and select install zip from sd card, and select gapps. And you're done!